# Вывести миниатюру в админке WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Я объявил новый тип постов, указал что должна быть миниатюра, но во время добавления этого поста у меня нет окна для добавления миниатюры. Хотя всегда добавлял типы постов, было все хорошо. Решил добавить еще один, и вот не добавляется миниатюра.

```
// Колонка миниатюры в списке записей
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_columns', 5);
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns', 5, 2);

function posts_columns($defaults)
{
    $defaults['riv_post_thumbs'] = __('Миниатюра');
    return $defaults;
}

function posts_custom_columns($column_name, $id)
{
    if ($column_name === 'riv_post_thumbs') {
        the_post_thumbnail(array(50, 50));
    }
}

function pages_columns($defaults)
{
    $defaults['riv_page_thumbs'] = __('Миниатюра');
    return $defaults;
}

function pages_custom_columns($column_name, $id)
{
    if ($column_name === 'riv_page_thumbs') {
        the_post_thumbnail(array(50, 50));
    }
}



    register_post_type('post-type-4', array(
            'label' => null,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Партнеры', // основное название для типа записи
                'singular_name' => 'Партнеры', // название для одной записи этого типа
                'add_new' => 'Добавить Партнера', // для добавления новой записи
                'add_new_item' => 'Добавление Партнера', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
                'edit_item' => 'Редактирование Партнера', // для редактирования типа записи
                'new_item' => 'Новый Партнер', // текст новой записи
                'view_item' => 'Смотреть Партнера', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
                'search_items' => 'Искать Партнера', // для поиска по этим типам записи
                'not_found' => 'Партнер не найден', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'Партнер не найден в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
                'parent_item_colon' => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
                'menu_name' => 'Партнеры', // название меню
            ),
            'description' => '',
            'public' => true,
            // 'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
            // 'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
            'show_in_menu' => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
            // 'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // зависит от show_in_menu
            'show_in_rest' => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
            'rest_base' => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
            'menu_position' => null,
            'menu_icon' => null,
            //'capability_type'   => 'post',
            //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
            //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
            // 'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'], // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
            // 'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'has_archive' => false,
            // 'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'uslugi/arenda-specztekhniki'),
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-thumbs-up', // иконка в меню
        ));
```

Comment: А в самой теме написали поддержку миниатюр ?

Comment: Да, конечно, добавил в код поддержку миниатюр

Comment: Справа вверху- настройки экрана (для классического редактора) - проверял?